# Subclass constructor with extra attributes

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, attributes, subclass

If I have a class 'Dog' that extends another class 'Animal' and the Animal class has a constructor with several attributes like latinName, latinFamily etc. How should I create the constructor for the dog? Should I include all attributes that are found in Animal, and all the extra attributes that i want in Dog, like so:

```
public Animal(String latinName){
    this.latinName = latinName;
}

public Dog(String latinName, breed){
    super(latinName);
    this.breed = breed;
}
```

The actual classes have far more attributes than I listed here, therefor the constructor for the dog becomes rather long, and had me doubting if this was the way to go or if there is a neater way?

Comment: Yes, this is the way to proceed. You can encapsulate the parameters in a map or in a wrapper class for readability if you want.

Comment: You are correct, include all attributes that are found in Animal, and all the extra attributes that you want in Dog class. Just correct your code with datatype in parameters. like `public Dog(String latinName, DataTypeOfBreed breed)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I include all attributes that are found in Animal...

Those that aren't invariant for dogs, yes (one way or another; see below). But for instance, if `Animal` has `latinFamily`, then you don't need `Dog` to have it, as that's always going to be `"Canidae"`. E.g.:

```
public Animal(String latinFamily){
    this.latinFamily = latinFamily;
}

public Dog(String breed){
    super("Canidae");
    this.breed = breed;
}
```

If you're finding the number of arguments to the constructor to be unweildy, you could consider the Builder pattern:

```
public class Dog {

    public Dog(String a, String b, String c) {
        super("Canidae");
        // ...
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private String a;
        private String b;
        private String c;

        public Builder() {
            this.a = null;
            this.b = null;
            this.c = null;
        }

        public Builder withA(String a) {
            this.a = a;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withB(String b) {
            this.b = b;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withC(String c) {
            this.c = c;
            return this;
        }

        public Dog build() {
            if (this.a == null || this.b == null || this.c == null) {
                throw new InvalidStateException();
            }

            return new Dog(this.a, this.b, this.c);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Dog dog = Dog.Builder()
            .withA("value for a")
            .withB("value for b")
            .withC("value for c")
            .build();
```

This makes it easier to be clear about which argument is which, as oppposed to a long string of arguments to a constructor. You get the benefits of clarity (you know `withA` is specifying the "a" information, `withB` is specifying "b", etc.) but without the danger of having a half-built `Dog` instance (since partially-constructed instances are poor practice); `Dog.Builder` stores up the information, and then `build` does the work of constructing `Dog`.

Comment: Interesting builder pattern as an alternative for long argument lists.

Answer (score 0):

If Dog extends Animal then yes, you would want to proceed using Animal's arguments (because a dog is indeed an animal) and *possibly* add more to distinguish between dog and animal objects.

So on a general note yes you would need to include all of the parent classes' arguments.

Also consider the possibility of multiple constructors with possibly shorter list of arguments. Say Animal takes an argument `String type` which defines what type of animal the child class is, you should not need to pass it every time for `Dog`.

```
public Dog (String name){
   super("Dog", name);
}
```

If I'm ambiguous with all this please do tell, I'll try to clear it up as much as I can.